Looker Pro upgrade
I am trying to create a Looker dashboard as part of a project on GCP but I am getting an error that I don't have permission to access the dashboard even though I am the super admin and I am using a single account for all Google services including Looker Studio. I thought of upgrading to Looker Studio Pro but it is also not allowing me to. I am getting the attached error message. Any recommendations?
Error:
(https://i.sstatic.net/FyxRb3MV.png)
I checked my user privileges, updated my billing information and basically everything that was mentioned in the documentation.
